# Clear WMS layer before redraw on OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layer, wms

I'm currently successfully displaying multiple layers using OpenLayers (Vector and WMS).
My application allow the user to modify some parameters, which will :
* modify bound
* modify map center
* modify the WMS image
I use Ajax to avoid page reload, it works nicely, however when some layers take a while to load, the others which are not yet redrawn are still shown in the background (but aren't related at all to my new context).
I would like to clear WMS layers (if possible) before re-asking the server for the new image but didn't find anything yet.
I do this on the vector layer by calling removeAllFeature();

Thanks for any help !

Here is my pseudo-code when the user click the button :

```
$.getJSON("url/updateMapConfig.php",
    {  
      data: $(this).serialize() ,   
      ajax: 'true',   
      cache: 'false'  
    },   
    function(j){  
      if (j.result == 'ok') {  
        var layersToShow = [];  
        // Refresh vector layer  
        for(var i=0;i<map.layers.length;i++) {  
          if (map.layers[i].isVector) {  
            map.layers[i].removeAllFeatures();  
            map.layers[i].refresh({force:true}); // Vector layer  
          }   
        }  
        // Refresh visible layers  
        for(var i=0;i<map.layers.length;i++) {  
          if (map.layers[i].visibility && !map.layers[i].isBaseLayer && !map.layers[i].isVector) { // Refresh visible non base  
              map.layers[i].redraw(true); // Other layer  
          }  
        }  
        // Set new bounds  
        var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds();  
          bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(j.bounds.xmin-100, j.bounds.ymin-100));  
          bounds.extend(new OpenLayers.LonLat(parseInt(j.bounds.xmax)+100, parseInt(j.bounds.ymax)+100));  
        map.zoomToExtent(bounds);  
        // Move to destination point  
        if (j.poiCenter != "") {  
          eval("map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat("+j.poiCenter+"))");  
        }  
      }  
    }  
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out an happy ending using the clearGrid() function on every layer before redrawing them.

I also found that this function will stop tile loading if any is running.
Example I had two base layer : EmptyLayer and WhateverTiledBGLayer.
if it tooks 20s to load WhateverTiledBGLayer tiles, even if the user chose to switch to empty layer, I could see the request done to the server for the remaining tiles on WhateverTiledBGLayer.

Simply calling WhateverTiledBGLayer.clearGrid() will stop requesting layers.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [mergeNewParams](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/WMS-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.WMS.mergeNewParams) to set a param that makes the layer draw blank. That method triggers a redraw of the layer. When your callback returns from your update request, you do the opposite to make it draw the layer correctly again.

(I have done something similar to this, but I don't have the source for now)

EDIT:

Or - of course - hide the layers with the [visibility](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.visibility) property of the layers. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do :  map.layers[i].setVisibility(false);     map.layers[i].setVisibility(true); Yet the layer still remain until it's redrawn, strange enough. I'll try the mergeNewParams

Comment: Maybe you have to force a redraw when setting visibility? Althought it seems unlikely...

Comment: Looking at your code more closely, I don't see any code that clears or hide the raster layers. Your function(j) is the success handler, but where do you refresh your map config? Maybe I'm not getting this...

Comment: Technically my WMS server generates using data in user SESSION, so I send an Ajax request that modify the user SESSION. Once it did, I just redraw the layers ("for(var i=0;i<map.layers.length;i++) {").

Comment: Ok. But I can't see any code that tries to hide the layers prior to the redraw() call. Where do you do that?

Comment: You're right it's not in this version (as I tried that after your recommendation). Now I : hide all visible layer (and keep the list in an array), modify bounds/center, redraw these layers and then show them back. For big layers I got this glitch where a part of the old image is shown during 2/3s

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to WMS layer's loadstart and loadend event and hide/show layer accordingly.

A quick test showed though that you can't set visibility of the layer to false on loadstart because OpenLayers will then stop requesting new images for the layer and it will never be completely loaded. You could though try with layer.display(false/true) and see if it solves your problem. The code should look something like this:

> ```
>   yourWmsLayer.events.on({
>         "loadstart" : function(){
>             this.display(false);
>         },
>         "loadend" : function(){
>             this.display(true);
>         } 
>     });
> ```

BTW, if you don't set transitionEffect to "resize" on your WMS layer then the default behavior is that old images are removed before new ones are loaded. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't have a transitionEffect and yet the old image isn't removed, I'll try Niklas solution and then yours if it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Ok I tried both solution and the behaviour doesn't change however I have discovered that my problem explanation wasn't good. In fact, the layer is hidden, then the loadend event is triggered and the layer reappear. But it takes sometime after the event before the layer shows the new image (1000x600). And during this time a part of the old image is shown.

Comment: then you can try to add a timer so that you set this.display(true) few seconds after loadend triggers. Something like this inside loadend callback  - setTimeout("this.display(true)", 3000);