# Refresh openlayers map after updating chart element

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I need to refresh an openlayers map after updating the size of pie charts in a mapfile displayed on the map (on button click). I cannot refresh the whole page or I lose the data. It works when I change the zoom level. I have tried map.updateSize() (no effect), map.render() (TypeError "a" is not defined), layer.redraw(). I am not sure if I am missing something openlayers-related, or if it is an issue with my javascript. I have looked through a number of posts, but can't seem to get any of the answers working in my case.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' ,
    { maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds({{bounds.0}}, {{bounds.1}}, {{bounds.2}}, {{bounds.3}}),
    controls:[new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
               new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
               new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()],
     numZoomLevels:20
     }
     );
     var mpLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.MapServer('Zones Layer', '{{ mapserverpath }}', { 
                map:'{{mapFile}}',
                layers:'all',
                isBaseLayer: 'true'
                },{
                    singleTile: 'true'
//                  ratio: 2.0
                }
            );

    map.addLayers([mpLayer]);
    //map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();  

    map.events.register("click", map, qryDB );

    $(document).on('click', '#bttnMinus', function(){
        pieFact*=0.5;
        updatePieFact();
        mpLayer.redraw();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#bttnPlus', function(){
        pieFact*=1.5;
        updatePieFact();
        mpLayer.redraw();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#bttnReset', function(){
        pieFact=1.0;
        updatePieFact();
        mpLayer.redraw();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call ["clearGrid()"](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Grid-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Grid.clearGrid) function before redrawing.

*"clearGrid()"* is a function of *Layer.Grid* (*Layer.MapServer* inherits from *Layer.Grid*). It will destroy each tile of the layers.

Just remark that "clearGrid ()" is not a APIMethod, so it is not supposed to be called in this way.

There are also a similar question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080685/1579961).

Answer (score 0):

try this. It worked for me.

$(window).trigger('resize');

This code sets the screen again.